# My mobile site has strange word spacing I need help normalizing

Tags: html, css

For some reason, some words have a lot more space before/after other words on my mobile site. I think this may be due to longer words are moved to another row and it wants the paragraph width to still = 100%. So I think if I can force hyphens it will remedy this; however, adding:

```
p {
hyphens: auto;
}
```

to the css of had no effect. Any suggestions? Common culprits?

I have also tried:

```
p {
hyphens: auto !important;
}
```

as well as "manual:" variants of this. for exampe:

```
p {
hyphens: manual !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Did you validate your HTML and CSS codes?

[W3C CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

[W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Thank you. It says "Congratulations! No Error Found." I've notice a lot of major websites have this issue as well. I'm sure there must be a way to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if `text-align`ist set to `justify`

Try to add `p { text-align: left; }`

Comment: ist the text justified, i.e. are the right-most words all aligned right?

Comment: No, it seems like just several random words on both the left and right side have a lot of space before/after them, while other words don't.

Comment: did you maybe assign `display: flex`to the container (= `p` tags)?

Comment: Nah.. Nothing like that.

Comment: well, hard to say then. you should post your complete code, HTML and CSS. Otherwise it's just guessing ...

Answer (score 0):

Your text probably has the CSS property

```
text-align: justify;
```

You can reset this with `text-align: left;`

You also tried to use `hyphens: auto;`, but I have to tell you that this property is **not supported by many modern browsers, including Google Chrome**. http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

However, if you want to use hyphenation, you can use *Hyphenator*, an easy to use javascript that hyphenates your website: https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator

I hope I could help!

Comment: Dang, this worked to hyphenate but didn't fix the spacing problem lol. Thanks anyways :)